# Apache and LDAP autentication + ErrorDocument

Tags: apache-2.4, ldap, errordocument

I use Apache 2.4 and mod_authnz toauthentication user from the AD.
And I have few questions:

1) I use the following code:

```
<Location "/*">
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative off
LDAPReferrals off

AuthName "Password protected. Enter your AD username and password."
AuthLDAPURL "url to AD"
AuthLDAPBindDN "User dn"
AuthLDAPBindPassword pass
Require ldap-group CN= group 

ErrorDocument 401 /error401.html
ErrorDocument 403 "<html><meta content=\"0;url=/noauth.html\" ><h3> Hi - 403 </h3></html>"
ErrorDocument 500 "<html><meta content=\"0;url=/noauth.html\" ><h3> Hi - 500 </h3></html>"
</Location>
```

Where should I put it? right now I put it in the httpd.conf file

2) The login popup is keep coming endless if i insert wrong details, there is a way to limit the tryouts?

I thought it is related to this line:

```
LDAPReferrals off
```

but with "On" its doesn't work

3) This line:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /error401.html
```

isn't working, it's not redirecting to this html, actually its make the authentication disappear. (the web is up no need to authenticate)

How can I direct the error to a specific html file? in another location?

I have tries multiple ways to write the path, full path, put the file in the htdocs folder but without success.

Thank you very much for any help!